# Trouble showing datepicker dialog fragment using Navigation component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment, android-architecture-navigation

I am trying to use the Navigation Component to show a date picker dialog fragment. I am getting the following error:

> android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

This is my DatePicker class

```
class DatePickerFragment : DialogFragment(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

var datePickerListener: DatePickerFragmentListener? = null

override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    val c = Calendar.getInstance()
    val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
    val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
    val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return DatePickerDialog(VitrixDataCollectionApp.context, this, year, month, day)
}

interface DatePickerFragmentListener {
    fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker, year: Int, month: Int, day: Int)
}

override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker, year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {
    datePickerListener?.onDateSet(view,year, month, day)
}
}
```

I would like to show the date picker when a TextInputField has focus. Here is my code to Navigate to the DatePicker

```
private fun showDatePicker(hasFocus: Boolean, view: View) {
    Log.i(FRAGMENT_NAME, "Has focus $hasFocus")
    if (hasFocus) {
        Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_createPatientDetailsFragment_to_datePickerFragment)
    }
}
```

Here are the relevant parts of my navigation graph xml

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/createPatientDetailsFragment"
          android:name="com.datacollection.ui.patients.create_patient.patient_details.CreatePatientDetailsFragment"
          android:label="create_patient_details_fragment"
          tools:layout="@layout/create_patient_details_fragment">
    <action android:id="@+id/action_createPatientDetailsFragment_to_datePickerFragment"
            app:destination="@id/datePickerFragment"/>
</fragment>
<dialog
        android:id="@+id/datePickerFragment"
        android:name="com.datacollection.ui.DatePickerFragment"/>
```

I am using Nav controller version: 2.1.0-alpha04

Here are my questions:

1. How do I get the dialog fragment to show?
2. How do I find the id of my DatePicker fragment, I sort of guessed it to be R.id.datePickerFragment

Let me know if you need any more info or need to see any more of my code.

Comment: make sure you are extending DialogFragment from `androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment`.

Comment: Yup, checked. I am using the androidx stuff.

Comment: It is working fine in my case.

Comment: Can you post your code as an answer, I wana compare it to mine just in case I missed something.

Comment: Issue is in your onCreateDialog. After passing application context in my code I am also getting the exception.

Comment: @DrkStr and how you pass DatePickerFragmentListener to your dialog with navigation components?

Comment: @Vahan I don't. Pretty sure you don't need to.

Comment: @DrkStr  I need. I need to make universal date picker dialog which can be called from different fragments or even many times from the same fragment for different dates to edit, so shared viewmodel isn't an answer. How can I appropriately update dates without listeners?

Comment: You can still use a shared view model. 
Just have the view model store each of your values separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1. How do I get the dialog fragment to show?**

Exception says **is your activity running?**
DialogFragment needs the context of activity/fragment instead of application. Update your below line of your `DatePickerFragment`

```
return DatePickerDialog(VitrixDataCollectionApp.context, this, year, month, day)
```

With

```
return DatePickerDialog(context, this, year, month, day)
```

in kotlin `context` is the property of framgent which you are extending. For java you can use `getContext()`.

Answer (score -1):

Use like this:

```
<dialog-fragment
    android:id="@+id/my_dialog"
    android:name="com.example.ui.MyDialogFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/my_dialog" />
```

Instead of:

```
<dialog
    android:id="@+id/datePickerFragment"
    android:name="com.datacollection.ui.DatePickerFragment"/>
```

For launch:

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.my_dialog)
```

In `Navigation Architecture Component` you can not use `dialog` directly.

Comment: Changing the tag from "dialog" to "dialog-fragment" gives me an "Element dialog-fragment is not allowed here" warning and crashes my app with a "Could not find Navigator with name "dialog-fragment". You must call NavController.addNavigator() for each navigation type." error on launch.

Comment: sorry for the downvote but according to the developer docs found here: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started#create-dialog -> "If you have an existing DialogFragment, you can use the <dialog> element to add the dialog to your navigation graph, as shown in the following example:"